# Live-Login with LiveAutchClient not working on real device

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, onedrive

I have a problem logging in with my Live-Account in my WP8 App.
In the Emulator everything works fine, but on the device (Lumia 820) it return the following server error:

```
    exception         {server_error: Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthClient.<LoginAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
    at MyOwnDiary.MainPage.<InitAuth>d__6a.MoveNext()}     System.Exception         {Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException}


    ErrorCode: -2146233088
```

Here is my Code:

```
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive_update" };
    try
    {
        this.authClient = new LiveAuthClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        LiveLoginResult loginResult = await this.authClient.InitializeAsync(scopes);
        if (loginResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            return true;
        }

        LiveLoginResult authResult = await this.authClient.LoginAsync(scopes);
        if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            App.Session = authResult.Session;
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error in Live-API: " + exp.Message);
        return false;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: When you run a debuger on a device and attach a breakpoint at line LiveLoginResult loginResult = await... ? Do you get in session property, an accesstoken? I assume that you first use signin and obtain access token.

Comment: No, I don't get a session or accesstoken. All Properties are null. The authResult hangs up with the errorcode above.

Comment: Are you able to login with provided SignIn button http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx#signin ?

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your API key. Make sure you are using the right app config.

[Live Connect Dev Center - My Apps](https://account.live.com/developers/applications)